# creating custom function for converting columns of data frame to factor

Tags: r

Hi I am giving labels to my data frame manually like below, I have 800 columns to be labeled , after that I am creating a subset of data frame (sub setting of data have many), then applying that data frame to function for calculation.

labels can be different for all chunks , also its very time taking for creating labels one by one for all chunks.

```
data<-data.frame(
    gender = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2),
    sector = c(3,3,1,2,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,4,3,4,2,1,4,2,3,4,4,4,3,1,2,1,5,5,4,3,1,4,5,2,3,4,5,1,4),
    col1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
    col2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
    col3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,1),
    col4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
    col5=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,NA,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
  )
  
  data$gender<-factor(data$gender, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Male","female"))
  data$sector<-factor(data$sector, levels=c(1,2,3,4,5), labels=c("TX","CA","NY","LA","WA"))
  data$col1<-factor(data$col1, levels=1, labels="Sales")
  data$col2<-factor(data$col2, levels=1, labels="OPS")
  data$col3<-factor(data$col3, levels=1, labels="Management")
  data$col4<-factor(data$col4, levels=1, labels="HR")
  data$col5<-factor(data$col5, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Local","Overseas"))
  
  df1<- data
  df1$cc1<-1
  df2<- subset(df, col5 == 'Local')
  df$cc2<-ifelse(df$col5 == 'Local',1,NA)
  lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
  ldat<-list("ALL" = df, "Local" =df2)
```

now I am looking for a function like where I can give a list of labels for eg .

```
factor_list <-  data.frame (colnames=c("col1","col2"....),col_labels =c("sales","OPS"....)
# so here I will be just needed to update factor list then the apply function for labelling

conv_frac <- function(dataset,var_bject){
for(i in 1:ldat)
lapply(factor,ldat(i))  # may be lapply or any thing else

}
# then  will apply factor_list
conv_frac(dataset = ldat,var_bject = factor_list)
```

any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function with the help of `Map` :

```
conv_frac <- function(dataset,cols, labels_list) {
  dataset[cols] <- Map(function(x, y) factor(x, labels = y), 
                       dataset[cols], labels_list)
  return(dataset)
}
```

Now pass dataframe, vector of column names and list of labels to it. For example, if you want to change 3 columns in `data` say `gender`, `col1` and `col2` you can do :

```
result <- conv_frac(data, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), 
                list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one', 'zero'), c('Sales', 'HR')))
head(result)

#   gender sector col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
#1    Male      3 zero    HR    1    1    1
#2  Female      3 zero    HR    1    0    2
#3    Male      1  one    HR    0    0    1
#4  Female      2  one    HR    0    0    1
#5    Male      5  one    HR    0    0    1
#6  Female      4  one Sales    0    0    2
```

This changes labels of only those columns keeping other columns as it is.

Comment: Hi i just updated NA in place of zero , please check that NA can also be handled, because there is no 0 in data base all are NA's

Comment: one more thing   , I want to apply for ldat 
conv_frac <- function(dataset,cols, labels_list)
dataset will always be ldat
i want to lapply the same for ldat like below

result <- conv_frac(ldat, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), 
                list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one', 'zero'), c('Sales', 'HR')))

Comment: Yes, you need to pass values in the list based on your data. So if you have `NA` and only 1 value then pass only 1 value in the list. `result <- conv_frac(data, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one'), c('Sales')))` works. `NA` would remain as `NA`.

Comment: thanks for your response but i am looking for a function where i can reduce time for giving labels for columns one by one.

i am looking for a function like where i can define labels first like 
factor_list <-  data.frame (colnames=c("col1","col2"....),col_labels =c("sales","OPS"....)

then i can just apply labels to list of subset (ldat)
conv_frac(dataset = ldat ,var_bject = factor_list)

Comment: If you define the label first or write in the function like what I have shown it will take same amount of time. There is no extra work you are doing here. Am I missing something?

Comment: actually i want create a function which will work for ldat  not to data frame itself for example  conv_frac(dataset = ldat,var_bject = factor_list) thats why i asked like looping or something else in my question

Comment: What do you mean by `ldat` ? List of dataframes ? In that case you can apply the function with `lapply`

Comment: yes list of dataframes , lapply inside or outside function

Comment: You can use `lapply` like this : `result <- lapply(ldat, function(x) conv_frac(x, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one'), c('Sales'))))`

Comment: I am getting this error while using for data 
result <- conv_frac(data, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), 
                      list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one', 'zero'), c('Sales', 'HR')))

 Error in factor(x, labels = y) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1

Comment: That is because your updated dataset has only 1 unique value in `col1` (i.e 1) excluding `NA` and you are passing two values to it i.e `c('one', 'zero')`. You need to pass only as many values as unique values is present in your data. See for example, this works : `conv_frac(data, c('gender', paste0('col', 1:2)), list(c('Male', 'Female'), c('one'), c('Sales')))`

Comment: @sanuali0123 Isn't this function doing the same thing as your recent question?

Comment: yes this did , but i was looking for very simple approach